# Can a generic method return the property I specify

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Yesterday Ognyan helped me a great deal write this method:

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static T AddIfNotExists<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : class, new()
    {
        var exists = predicate != null ? dbSet.Any(predicate) : dbSet.Any();
        return !exists ? dbSet.Add(entity) : null;
    }
}
```

When this does do an Add of my entity, I get back the new ID of the entity, but if it exists it returns null.

There will be times that I would like to get back the ID of an entity that already exists. However, the Key ID property of my entities will be different depending on the model. For instance, Address model's key is AddressId, Profile's key is ProfileId.

So, I'd like to modify this query (or make another version of it) to accept the Id property name as a parameter. (Or use EF to recognize the Primary key.) And do something like this:

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static T AddIfNotExists<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet,  
        T entity,  
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null,  
        Expression<Func<T, TId>> keyColumnName) where T : class, new()
    {
        var exists = predicate != null ? dbSet.Where(predicate).Select(e => e.keyColumnName) : dbSet.Any();
        return !exists ? dbSet.Add(entity) : exists ;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if that is the correct way to define the property I want to use. I also realize this may not be as fast as just doing an Any(), but at times it may be necessary for us to get the ID.

I would also like to understand better what all of these items mean and how they work together. I've been all over and gotten bits and pieces, but haven't been able to put the whole puzzle together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well maybe there is a better solution, but you can try this:

```
   public static TResult AddIfNotExists<T,TResult>(this DbSet<T> dbSet,  
                                                   T entity, 
                                                   Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate,
                                                   Expression<Func<T, TResult>> columns  
                                                  ) where T : class, new()
   {
       if (predicate==null || columns==null)
           throw new Exception();

       //Find if already exist the entity and select its key column(s)
       var result =  dbSet.Where(predicate).Select(columns).FirstOrDefault();

       //the result could be a reference type (string or anonymous type) or a value type
       if (result!=null && !result.Equals(default(TResult)))
           return result;

       var newElement = dbSet.Add(entity);

       //Compile the Expresion to get the Func
       var func = columns.Compile();
       //To select the new element key(s), add the element to an array (or List) to apply the Select method and get the keys
       var r = new[]{newElement};

       return r.Select(func).FirstOrDefault();
   }
```

As you can see, I always expect the parameters `predicate` to check if the element already exist and `columns` to select the key or keys in case you have an entity with composite PK (but notice you can select all the properties you want from that entity, not just the keys). Then, I apply the expressions to filter and select the key(s) in case the element exist. If it doesn't exist, I add the entity to its `DbSet<T>`, but there is a problem. How can you get the new element key(s)? Well, the only solution I found to this was adding that element to an array, compiling the expression to get a `Func<T,TResult>`, and apply that `Func<T,TResult>` to the array, (I know this may not be the best solution but it should work).

To call this extension method, for example, for an entity that have a composite PK, you can do this:

```
.AddIfNotExists(element, e => e.UserName== "admin", e => new{ e.Id1,e.Id2});
```

Answer (score 0):

The more simple in your case should be:

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static T AddIfNotExists<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, T entity,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : class, new()
    {
        T exists = predicate != null ?
            dbSet.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault():
            dbSet.FirstOrDefault();
        return exists == null ?
            dbSet.Add(entity):
            exists;
    }
}
```

then, as you seem to know the PK property, you can check it from the returned value.

Comment: That's what I originally thought, but wasn't quite happy with for 2 reasons. First, if the object/record returned is large. Some times we will have long description fields or even blobs. I thought getting just the ID would be faster. Second, I'm getting an object instead of a bool every time. In those cases where I don't need anything returned, just exists true/false, it seems like extra traffic. Am I over-complicating things with my thinking?